# Using java variables in Mysql where clause

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I wanted to use java variables in SQL syntax.Please suggest whether its possible or not.Here is my code

```
String Userid_input=request.getParameter("Userid");//I am getting dynamic input from User

String Password_input=request.getParameter("Password");
```

The database connection is being given below

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Proj_name","root","root");
Statement st=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select User_type from Signup where User_name.User_name=Userid_input");//**Userid_input** is a java variable
```

I am getting the following error ,

Exception occured com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column **'Userid_input'** in 'where clause'

Comment: `"select User_type from Signup where User_name.User_name=" + Userid_input`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
   String query = "select User_type from Signup where User_name.User_name="+Userid_input;
   ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
```

Reference : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html

Comment: Even now i am getting the following error                       Exception occuredcom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Vijay' in 'where clause'//Here 'Vijay' is the Userid_input value

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select User_type from Signup where User_name=" + Userid_input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use prepared statements:

> String query = "SELECT User_type FROM Signup WHERE User_name.User_name = ?";
>
> PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
>
> ps.setInt(1, Userid_input);
>
> ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

More about prepared statements http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: i tried this before itslef,but even then i am getting exception

Comment: Then possibly the column name is not right, note it's case sensitive for Unix/Linux/Mac (but not Windows).  Oh I just realized User_name.User_name is most likely incorrect should it not be just User_name, check the case as well.